# Push notification badge not updating in iOS 7.1 when app is closed or in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
   {
        aps =     {
            alert = "You have assigned 1 new task.";
            badge = 1;
            sound = "default"
        };
    }
```

The same JSON Payload is working in iOS 8+ but not in 7.1
Am I missing something here in payload?

I have checked for the notification settings and it's fine too.

Comment: are you getting notification?

Comment: Yes, except the badge, all working fine.